# How to change style in react-native dynamically?

Tags: css, react-native, react-devtools

As in react we can inspect element, see class applied to element and dynamically change css properties and can see in UI.Like wise do we have anything in react native?Tried react-devtools but tried to change css property value but that is not reflecting in UI.

Comment: you just need to look at the properties of CSS in react-devtool and change any property press enter and property will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have your style property and you can set a function.

```
<SomeComponent style={this.styleDefiningMethod()} ... />

styleDefiningMethod () { // pass a parameter that you want to be change in you style like let styleChange
    return {
        //your style definition e.g. background: '#ff00ff'
    }
}
```

Inside of your `styleDefiningMethod` you can add some logic based on your state or on parameter.